# how to get data property in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to get visits:4  this is my console

```
{
    "status": true,
    "visits": 4
}
```

how can i access "visits": 4 in data:[]

```
  const options = {
             
          series: [
            {
              name: "Total Visits",
              data: []
            }
          ],
   
        };
```

this is my request

```
 axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/api/visit")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        const counts = response.data.visits;
)}
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: And the issue is?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Does your existing code not do what you expected? Or do you want us to pick up where you left off?

Comment: And _please_ post code as text, not as images (you can edit your question).

Comment: How is the surrounding code structured? How do your two blocks related to one another? Are they separate, or does the first one immediately follow the second one?

Comment: You may have got a solution, but this question is not really helpful to anyone at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this this should work

```
data: [response.data.visits]
```